# Webpage extends beyond the HTML element

Tags: html, css

I have created a web page but have recently used the background gradient system to make it less harsh on the eyes. This has made me suddenly aware that the webpage extends past the point of the `<html>` element and continues to scroll further. This also causes the background gradient to repeat a second time below the `<body>` element.

Does anyone know a reason why this would happen and any way to either prevent the page from scrolling beyond the point of the `<html>` element or to prevent the background from repeating a 2nd time after the `<html>` tag?

Here is an example of it happening:

[image: Example screenshot]

Here is the CSS for the background:

```
body{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: rgba(18,87,182,0); /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 10%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 10%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 10%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 20%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Standard*/
}
```

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Would you like the entire code for the webpage or the specific code for the css element?

Comment: Wherever you think the problem might lie.

Comment: I suspect the problem lies within the html however I am unable to find any reason within my html that it would extend beyond the end point of the html tag. If you look at the screenshot I posted you can see in the console window that the html element ends but the page then continues down further with no further elements

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and post a link to us?

Comment: Please try to remove HTML and CSS as much as possible, but so that the problem can still be reproduced. Then post the HTML and CSS.

Comment: Ok, i've added a link to a jfiddle. Whist recreating the problem I found it is built of 2 issue, the first is an overextended div on a some pages but the problem continues where the html element is smaller than the size of the window.

Comment: I noticed your question had missing words, use Markdown to format your questions appropriately so we can see inline html code snippets and they make more sense. Here is a useful link https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Thank you, I will endeavour to do this in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, Add `background-attachment: fixed;` to your body,

```css
body{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background: rgba(18,87,182,0); /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 10%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Safari 5.1-6*/
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 10%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Opera 11.1-12*/
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 10%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Fx 3.6-15*/
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(86,213,251,1) 0%,rgba(18,87,182,0.5) 20%,rgba(255,0,0,0) 70%); /*Standard*/
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <section id="intro">
        <h1><strong>Welcome! </strong></h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        
        Writing goes here
        
        <strong> Please click <a>here</a> to begin helping with the alpha test.</strong>
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: That has fixed it, thank you for taking the time to show the "background-attachment" tag. Apologies if the question was easier than I made it seem